# -lgfortran library not found mac (linker command failed)

Tags: macos, terminal, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to run a program that uses the command -lgfortran on a mac. In the terminal, I run the .sh file using `sh myFile.sh`. When it runs I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lifcoremt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: library not found for -lifcoremt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed fortran and C compilers here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/compilers

I also did some digging and read that I should locate the `libgfortran.a` file and replace the `-lgfortran` command with the file path to that file (`/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/lib/gcc/9/libgfortran.a`).

I run my code and I get the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea how any of the fortran compiler stuff works and am new to using the terminal. How do I go about fixing this?

**EDIT**

`gcc --version`  gives:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

and `gfortan --version` gives:

```
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_3) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: But your issue seems to be related to this lib `-lifcoremt`. It looks like you have to pass proper location to this lib (seems like Intel's lib) - judging by it's name. You can also install `gcc` - with fortran: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-8-3-0/ and then, use modules to make sure you can easily jump between your systems compiler and one that you have installed: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/

Comment: When you say I have to pass proper location to -lifcoremt, what does that mean and how do I do this?

Comment: Typically, when you link with shared library you specify two things: `L/directory/where/the/lib/is` and the name of library `-lname_of_lib` (without `lib` prefix and without `.so` suffix). In your case, you have to make sure that `-L` points at location where the file `libifcoremt.so` - it's a part of your Intel based Fortran installation. It should be somewhere there.